# Как проектируется нейронная сеть?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Перечитал некоторое количество статей в интернете. Базовые примеры на 3-10 нейронов понятны, однако для реальных задач, насколько я знаю, используются намного более объёмные сети.

Опишите способ их проектирования? Каким образом люди дробят задачу?
Как разработчики определяют, что им понадобиться именно, например, 1105 нейронов, связанных только "таким" способом (архитектура) и каждый нейрон будет отвечать конкретно на "такой" вопрос, а не "какой-либо другой"?

Comment: общий вопрос чтоли

Comment: @PauloBerezini вопрос конкретный: "как они проектируются?" Но, согласен, интересует скорее общий обзор методов и подходов, ведь профильные статьи (из тех, что я нашёл) сразу ударяются в дебри, не оставляя шанса на понимание.

Comment: @CorellianAle  -  а учить не по статьям, а по книжкам -  не пробовали? Там все описывается -  подробно, регулярно, последовательно, понятно. И с логикой там все в порядке.  А не так, как в обрывочных статьях.

Comment: @passant До смешного - нет, не пробовали! И через 2 года могу сказать следующее:
1) За эти 2 года можно было бы любую теорию выучить и разобрать - никаких отговорок.
2) В лучших традициях, проблему закрыли готовым решением (быстро и дорого).

Answer (score 4):

Мало кто проектирует новые архитектуры НС (нейронных сетей) - таких людей единицы. В 99% случаев выбирается архитектура, которая хорошо себя показала (например побеждала в Kaggle/etc.). Под архитектурой я имею в виду наборы  и сочетания скрытых слоев, а не количество нейронов в одном слое.

> Опишите способ их проектирования? Каким образом люди дробят задачу?
> Как разработчики определяют, что им понадобиться именно, например,
> 1105 нейронов, связанных только "таким" способом (архитектура) и
> каждый нейрон будет отвечать конкретно на "такой" вопрос, а не
> "какой-либо другой"?

Обычно НС применяются в задачах с контролируемым обучением (supervised learning). Соответственно на этапе обучения НС знает к каким значениям ей надо стремится. Т.е. настроить веса и параметры сети таким образом, чтобы данные и тренировочного и особенно тестового наборов показывали наилучший результат. Поэтому обученная сеть отвечает на тот вопрос, на который она была обучена / натренирована.

---

Например глубокие НС, распозняющие различные объекты на картинках, обучаются следующим образом:

- на начальных слоях НС учится распознавать элементарные признаки, например границы / линии - горизонтальные, вертикальные, дианональные и т.д.
- на следующих слоях это могут быть, например дуги, и т.д.
- на еще более глубоких слоях это уже могут быть простые геометрические фигуры, например, прямоугольники, окружности, эллипсы, etc.
- с увеличением глубины слоя НС учится распознавать все более сложные / составные объекты, например глаза, нос, губы на лице и т.д.
- так можно научить сеть не просто распознать человека, но и заставить ее отличать, например лежащего человека или человека который один, не в группе других людей, etc.

Вся прелесть НС в том, что вы ей даете для обучения только две матрицы (входящую и результирующую) и архитектуру - все остальное НС делает сама.

Вам только надо следить чтобы сеть хорошо обучалась на тренировочных данных и не переобучалась...

Comment: Но существуется же какая-то логика, по которой люди модифицируют существующие нейронные сети. Делают они это, я думаю, вполне осознанно и с пониманием. Просто мне не совсем понятно, на чём именно основываются решения при модификации архитектуры. Не могу уловить, как от таких простых примеров, как [этот](https://geektimes.com/post/277088/) люди приходят к многослойным с десятками тысяч нейронов? Вроде почти любую ситуацию можно описать 10-20 нейронами, только так оно не работает.

Comment: На самом деле я до сих пор не понимаю, как я для своих целей могу подобрать кол-во скрытых слоев и тд. *"на начальных слоях НС учится распознавать элементарные признаки ..., на следующих слоях это могут быть, например дуги, и т.д."* - вот как можно понять какой элемент будет на определенном сочетании нейронов?

Comment: @entithat, почитайте о [визуализации слоев сверточных сетей](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-convolutional-features-in-40-lines-of-code-70b7d87b0030)

Answer (score 2):

все зависит от цели обучения. если работаешь с компьютерным зрением - одни сетки, с тексом и речью - другие. Данные собираются и готовятся по разному. Количество слоев и нейронов - в зависимости от задачи и ее сложности. Есть разные конфигурации - входной слой, скрытые слои, выходной слой и т.д. Слои, количество нейронов, активация, потери, и прочее в зависимости от задачи. Я сам новичок в этом деле, многое не знаю, многое забываю. Просто набираешь слои как в конструкторе, а какие и как - тут все от задачи зависит. Как-то так.
Можно брать готовые сетки в разных Model Zoo, kaggle. и знать, что сетки тоже ошибаются всегда.
Чем сложнее задача, тем больше нейронов, потому что больше входных данных, параметров. Есть генетические сети, сети с подкреплением -для игр и т.д, там может быть большое количество вариантов действий - много нейронов что бы их учесть и обработать - там веса могут вообще не назначать, потому что они в процессе обучения расчитываются сами.